# How can I calculate the following integration $\int \frac {1}{(y^2 - 10y + 25) ^{ 20}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I calculate the following integration $$\int \frac {1}{(y^2 - 10y + 25) ^ {20}}$$?
If it were without the power of 20 it can be easily calculated with partial fractions method, but now I can not solve it, any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by *recognising* the perfect square in the denominator.

The integral is in fact $\displaystyle \int \frac 1{(y-5)^{40}}dy$

A simple $u = y-5$ substitution does the trick.

Comment: I'm still wondering why this deserved a downvote. If there's a legitimate reason, I wish it had been stated (rather than hiding behind anonymity). Of course, if it had been simple retribution, I'd be very disappointed.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use $y^2-10y+25=(y-5)^2$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Complete the square, then do a $u$-substitution.

Comment: Nothing to complete ...

Comment: @Eric Towers: this is true, but some people like to rely on a method. This is how a problem like this should be approached. Regardless, one must factor the denominator.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. The thing that makes *this* problem *so simple* is that *no* completion of the square is needed. If non-trivial completion of the square were to be required by the addition of a non-zero constant, and you end up with something like $\int \frac 1{((y-5)^2+5)^{20}}dx$, the solution and the final answer come out being a godawful mess. So I don't think this answer is very helpful at all.

Comment: @Deepak: you are entitled to believe that: it does not change the fact that using the formula for completing the square makes it obvious what it reduces to (hence a short hint). Furthermore, as I have already said in a previous comment: many people like a straightforward approach. This *is* the straightforward approach. Regardless of what it comes down to *after* completing the square, this is undoubtedly the first step (see all of the other answers: **recognize this is a square** but if one does not recognize it, then what?)

Comment: A much better (in my opinion, less misleading) hint here would've been "observe that the denominator is a perfect square" rather than "complete the square".

Comment: BTW, just in case anyone needs convincing of the difference - original problem: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F(x%5E2+-+10x+%2B+25)%5E20, and a modified one: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F(x%5E2+-+10x+%2B+30)%5E20

Comment: @Deepak: see my edit in the comment above, please.

Comment: @Clayton I don't wish to prolong the discussion, so I'll end with this. My point is that by presenting this as a "straightforward approach", a naive student might be misled into thinking this sort of thing would give a simple answer when *actual non-trivial completion of the square is needed*. My example shows that assumption would be wrong. Sometimes, *recognition* of a standard form is more important than "blindly" applying a *rote* "straightforward" method.